# Autohotkey Ctrl+Shift - Zbrush/Photoshop

Tags: autohotkey, remapping

I have been using Autohotkey for a long time to remap keys inside CG softwares (mainly Zbrush and Photoshop) to make them more lefty-friendly.

Essentially, I remap the Numpad keys to keys you can't change inside the programs (Ctrl, Alt, Shift, etc...). This way I can use my graphics tablet pen with my left hand and access Ctrl, Alt, etc. using the Numpad, which is much more convenient than offsetting the whole keyboard to the right.

Anyway, here is my script :

```
 #IfWinActive, ahk_class ZBrush

 #MaxHotkeysPerInterval 200



 NumPad1::Alt

 Numpad2::LControl

 Right::Shift

 up::Space

 return
```

Pretty simple, but I have had a bug with it ever since I created it several years ago. Essentially, when I am pressing and holding Numpad2+Right (Ctrl+Shift), and release Numpad2, the program behaves as if I was still pressing it. Repressing Numpad2 real quick sets it back to normal but it's very annoying. Here are a couple of images to better illustrate the issue :

[image]

Do you know why this happens? I am no programmer, so I could definitely use some help.

Comment: Try using `Send` (or its variants) instead.

Comment: Hey! Thank you, I tried using the Send command but it didn't do much...

Numpad2::Send {LControl Down}
        
 Numpad2 Up::Send {LControl Up}
        
 Right::Send {Shift Down}

 Right up::Send {Shift up}

The problem doesn't seem to happen when I release Right before Numpad2. It's as if pressing Right (Shift) prevented Numpad2 (Ctrl) from being released...

Comment: Ah okay, I see now; I’ll post an explanation in a moment…

Comment: (Don’t forget that you don’t *have* to accommodate limits like this; you can can always just submit a bug-report/feature-request to make it easier to use, especially for paid software like [ZBrush](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop.html) and [Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop.html).) `;-)`

Comment: Haha ^^ Well, perhaps later versions of Zbrush will be more lefty-friendly or allow customization of the navigation / mode toggle keys ^^ In the meantime you gotta find a solution for yourself, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem doesn't seem to happen when I release Right before Numpad2. It's as if pressing Right (Shift) prevented Numpad2 (Ctrl) from being released...

The problem you are seeing is due to the fact that the numeric keypad is altered by <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> is similar to toggling the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key, but the effect is more complex and non-obvious.

For example, pressing <kbd>Numpad-4</kbd> would produce the following results:

```
          │ Num On │ Num Off
──────────┼────────┼───────────
Shift Off │   4    │    ←
──────────┼────────┼───────────
Shift On  │   ←    │ Shift + ←
```

Because you are remapping <kbd>→</kbd> to be <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> and using it in combination with a key in the numeric-pad, you are getting an interaction that is complicating AutoHotkey and confusing you with its unexpected result (it may very well be the *logically correct*, but certainly unexpected and unwanted result).

Try changing your secondary key from <kbd>Numpad-2</kbd> to something else which is *not* modified by <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>, such as <kbd>K</kbd>. You will notice that you no longer get the unexpected results.

This behavior occurs in the keyboard controller, not software, so unfortunately, if you need to use <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> as a modifer, then you cannot use a numeric-pad key for complex remappings like this.

One option is to use the editing block or the numeric-pad keys that are not modified by <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> (the mathematical operators, <kbd>Numpad-5</kbd>, and <kbd>Numpad-Enter</kbd>).

Another option is to write a more complicated script that creates a keyboard-hook to check keys at a lower level, so that it can check to see if the <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> key is down, then compensate as necessary.

(I ran into this very problem a while back when I wrote a Unicode-entering program. I was trying to make it support shifting keys for certain characters, but the modification was messing things up. I ended up resorting to the latter suggestion and writing a complicated script, but it was frustrating, dizzying, and ultimately ended up being kind of limited anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Awesome reply! Fast and precise. Thank you so much. I didn't realise those keys were modified by Shift,  giving me this annoying behaviour. The thing is I am so used to this Numpad2 remap that I cannot afford to change it without going through weeks of psychomotor readaptation ^^

I managed to bypass the problem by just remapping NumpadDown to Ctrl as well ^^ I works wonders now !

```
NumPad1::Alt

Numpad2::Ctrl

NumpadDown::Ctrl

Right::Shift

up::Space

    return
```

Thank you so much for pointing out the origin of the problem. This had been bugging me for years.

Comment: Yes, you added the second mode (I seem to have glossed over that part), but be careful about the NumLock; if it is off you’ll get different behavior. Accounting for every combination is difficult and won’t work as desired anyway, so make sure that NumLock stays the same (you can even [specifically set](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm) it in your script to be sure it—starts out—in the correct state).

Comment: Will do, mate. I tried changing the default Zbrush shortcuts but, as in most cg programs, Alt, Shift and Ctrl are just hard-coded and can't be changed. I wish I just didn't have to use Shift, but there's no way around it. I don't have that many combinations to account for anyway. That very one was buggy and remapping both Numpad2 and NumpadDown to Ctrl gives me just the behaviour I want, so everything's great :) Thank you again!